# PyQt5 - Adding a Widget from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have this simple code and I can't figure out why it does not work.

I tried to call the function "AddOneWidget" from the "**init**" function, and it works (commented line).

But if the thread calls the function from outside, it does not show any new Widget, but it prints the message, which indicates that this code is actually executed. I also tried to use the function "show()" after adding the Widget without success. I use a global variable "window" to refer to my main window.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys
import threading as th


def ModifyWindow():
    global window
    window.AddOneWidget()
    
    
class some_timer_thread(th.Thread):
   def __init__(self, event):
        th.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event
        
   def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(1):
            ModifyWindow() 
        
           
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.central)
        
        self.show()
        #self.AddOneWidget()
        

        
    def AddOneWidget(self):
        print('Lets add a label')
        self.someLabel = QLabel('hello')
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.someLabel)

    


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
# create the instance of our Window
window = MainWindow()

#start timer thread
thread_lfs_stopflag = th.Event()
thread_lfs = some_timer_thread(thread_lfs_stopflag)
thread_lfs.start()

# start the app
resultexec = App.exec()

# End program, close timers
thread_lfs_stopflag.set()

sys.exit(resultexec)
```

Comment: Use a `QThread` instead of a python thread. have the Qthread emit a signal, and connect that signal to the AddWidget method.

Comment: UI elements are not thread safe and can **not** be created in external threads. Do as suggested above, and also do not use globals.